# Product collection filtering/order direction issue

Tags: magento, sorting, collections, position, product

For my category view. I have a select drop down which uses ajax to set a session with the option value.

I have overridden `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`.

This session value processed from ajax is called in the '`protected function _getProductCollection()`' override to filter the product collection as needed.

My first problem is that I would like to filter by an attribute, based on three values on these attributes:

```
 $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
 $collection ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('in' => array('Cat','Adam', 'Paul')));
 $collection->addAttributeToSort('name = Cat', 'DESC');
 $collection->addAttributeToSort('name = Adam', 'DESC');
 $collection->addAttributeToSort('name = Paul', 'DESC');

  return $this->_productCollection;
```

The problem is that I want to position these as needed. For example I need Cat first then Adam then Paul. Is there any way to position these?

The second issue is that I need position an '`sort by`' option. '`asc`' is the default, however what I need it for descending to be default.

So far I have overridden `'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar'` and used this code:

```
protected $_direction           = 'desc';
```

This however is not changing the direction.

Will the sort by take precedence over the custom product collection I have created?

LOG

a:5:{i:0;s:126:"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FIND_IN_SET'";i:1;s:6707:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(825): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(225): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(211): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1036): Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Observer.php(78): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1334): Mage_Review_Model_Observer->catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1307): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Review_Model_Observer), 'catalogBlockPro...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_block_p...', Array)
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(163): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_p...', Array)
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_list', true)
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php(85): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_list')
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/design/frontend/default/gomer/template/catalog/category/view.phtml(115): Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View->getProductListHtml()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/design/frontend/default/gomer/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(49): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(159): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/mypath/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
{main}";s:3:"url";s:72:"/mypath/index.php/books-for-adults/autobiography-and-biography.html";s:11:"script_name";s:22:"/mypath/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"english";}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use finset:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('finset'=>array('Cat','Adam','Paul')));
```

finset uses the FIND_IN_SET function of MySQL

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried the code but my product collection is returning the no matching products message. I have tried: $collection ->addAttributeToFilter('language', array('in' => array('Cat', 'Adam', 'Paul'))); which gives the products (in the wrong order)

Comment: hope you didn't copy my typo by not submitting an array to finset. i corrected that now.

Comment: I also tried that, however it gives me a security exception screen. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: could you try to assebmle the select and get its output? Mage::log($collection->getSelect()->assemble());

Comment: do this in the overriden class. you should not deal with setting up collection in the view, only read them :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added this code in my overridden class but I get no information in my log. Just to check would the right place to check be var/log/system.log

Comment: yes that's the right place. are you sure you have overriden the class correctly?

Comment: Yes I have, I have a session set in list.phtml with a value. The overridden class uses this value in an series of if statements to filter the product collection. The filtering works (apart from this sort) If it helps could I post my overridden class?

Comment: What happens if you try to log something else? Just to be sure the code is executed at that point of code.

Comment: Sorry, I done the code in the wrong if statement condition. I had trouble pasting the contents of the log on here so I uploaded it: http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1360083940